# Synonym of Dream Interpreter

Tags: synonyms, american-english, vocabulary, language-evolution

Is there any single word synonym from "Dream Interpreter" or the person who tells the meaning of the dream?

Answer (score 2):

The exact word that you are looking for is **Oneirocriticism.**

Oxford Dictionary defines [*Oneirocriticism*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/oneirocriticism) as

> : The art or practice of interpreting dreams.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oneirocriticism) also backs it.

---

NOTE: [**Oneirology**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oneirology) is a scientific study of dreams and it is different from Oneirocriticism.

On the other hand, [**Oneiromancy**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/oneiromancy) is divination through dreams i.e. you see dreams sent by God or demigods and predict the future.

Oxford Dictionary defines *[Oneiromancy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/oneiromancy)* as

> :The interpretation of dreams in order to foretell the future.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oneiromancy) also back it.

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oneiromancy), Oneiromancy (from the Greek όνειροϛ oneiros, dream, and μαντεία manteia, prophecy) is a form of divination based upon dreams; it is a system of dream interpretation that uses dreams to predict the future.